# importing function giving scoping error

Tags: python, import, scope

Suppose we save the following into a Python file called `test.py`:

```
x = 14

def print_x():
    print x

def increment_x():
    x += 1
```

and then run the following from an interactive Python shell in the same directory:

```
from test import print_x, increment_x

print_x()
increment_x()
print x
```

Why does the third call produce an error? Doesn't `x` need to be defined for the first two to work?

Comment: AFAIK `increment_x()` must also throw an error

Answer (score 0):

The functions do not throw an error because they still live in the module test, and they still see x in the module test. When you import a reference to a function elsewhere it dose not really move, or become disconnected from its original context. If it did there wouldn't be much use for modules.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a Scope error message is because `x` is only global in `test.py` and when you do:

```
from test import print_x, increment_x
```

You are not actually importing x to the global scope of the second script.

So, if you want to make x global as well in the second script, do:

```
from test import *
```

Try to use the **DEBUGGER** utility within IDLE to see when `x` is `GLOBAL` and when is not